# XPath find a child node by class name

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Ok, so I have one of those multi-auto-inputs, that for selenium requires me to enter some text in them, then wait until the list is visible and press tab.

I do this with the following code:

```
we.sendKeys(initialInput);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-1\"]")));
we.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

This is inside a method that receives a WebElement we which is the input area of the multi-auto-input.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<ul id="contactPersonDataWrap" class="inputAutoText tagit" data-id="contactPersonData" data-what="contactPersonDataGeneral" data-strict="1" data-max-tags="1" data-events="" data-extra-params="branchData" data-max-length="1000">
  <li class="tagit-new">
    <input class="tagit-input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="1000" name="contactPersonDataInput" autocomplete="off">
  </li>
    <ul id="ui-id-3" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none;">  
  </ul>
</ul>
```

This is the second one, the first is exactly the same, but the id is ui-id-1 and the name of the input is different as well.

I wanted a solution that works even in a page with N of them, that, given the WebElement for the input, I can simply wait for the list to load.

Comment: Share the HTML bro

Comment: @ChandraShekhar there it is!

Comment: How is `initialInput` declared? Does `ui-id-1`, `ui-id-2` & `ui-id-3` receives the same text (i.e. `initialInput`) ?

Comment: @DebanjanB initialInput is just a String, because sometimes just sending an "a" and waiting doesn't work, or in case I need to select a specific one.

Comment: This is a page with only two auto-fill inputs, they need a small text to start loading and then a list shows up and I press tab to input the first one.

The id's are auto-generated, so that's why they're "ui-id-1" "ui-id-2".

I want a generic way to select that list from a web-element being passed to the method

Sometimes "a" works, sometimes I need something like "she" to select a specific one.

Comment: @brightpants IMO, we need to get into the HTML DOM. To `press tab to input the first one` is not a good practice. We should be able to work with the element/node attributes e.g. `id`, `name`, `linkText`, `xpath` or `css` with desired locators irrespective they are static or dynamic.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm aware, but this is just some basic testing, I didn't want to complicate it.

How would I do to navigate from an element to it's parent and then to the first `ul ` it finds?

Comment: @brightpants I think we should setup/finalize the framework and the methods right from the initial stage whether it is a POC or a basic testing. Navigating from an element to it's parent and then to the first `ul` is very much feasible and possible using dynamic `css` and dynamic `xpath`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153870/discussion-between-brightpants-and-debanjanb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got you correct, You need a generic `xpath` to identify any list after entering data.

You can have your xpath, Try this xpath:

```
   //ul[contains(@class,'inputAutoText')]//ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete ui-front') and contains(@id,'ui-id-')]
```

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Comment: Actually, what I need is: 

I pass a WebElement to this method, and through this WebElement, I need to get the specific list that shows up for the auto-complete, because I need to wait until it finishes loading to press tab and select one. 

The structure of the html is there, I actually wrote it wrong the first time, I need to wait until

Comment: `<ul id="ui-id-3" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none;">`  loads, and I need to access it from the WebElement being passed to it, in this case, the WebElement associated is the `<input class="tagit-input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="1000" name="contactPersonDataInput" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Ok! What if we try this:

Comment: List<WebElement> retrievingObject = passedElement.findElements(By.Xpath("//ul[contains(@id='ui-id') and contains(text(),'<Text you looking for>')]"));  If you know what you need to select from the drop down list.

Comment: You can wait till the passedElement.count is greater than Zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `xpaths` in your code:

```
//ul[contains(@class,'inputAutoText')]//ul[contains(@id,'ui-id')]

 //ul[contains(@class,'inputAutoText')]//ul[contains(@id,'ui-id-"+N thnumber+"')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited a bit yours, and in the end my wait was:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(we.findElement(By.xpath("../following-sibling::*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]")))); `